# Закрепить кнопку при выдвижении клавиатуры

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

Собственно задача такая: есть карточка и несколько текстовых полей, нужно смещать их при выдвижении клавы так, чтобы кнопка, привязанная ко дну, всегда была над клавиатурой. Желательно, не добавляя никаких тегов в манифест к активити.

Сделал через старый трюк с ScrollView с текстовыми полями и fitsSystemWindows = true. Работает, но при скрытии клавы, вьюхи возвращаются обратно с отступом сверху (предположительно равному размеру статус бара).

Вопрос, можно как-то исправить это косяк? Или как иначе сделать, быть может как-то через behaviour и coordinatorLayout?

Структура разметки такая:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/typeCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    //тут ещё пара вьюх,  не суть

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/completeButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/typeCardView">

    //тут поля ввода 

</ScrollView>

<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/completeButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_padding"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:text="@string/order_delivery_complete"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AccentButton"
    app:cornerRadius="2dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что у вас там за трюк такой, но я с этим косяком наверное час три пропарился.

У меня была примерно следующая конструкция:

```
<ConstrainLayout
  ...>
  <ScrollView 
    ...
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"//покрайней мере у меня вся отвязалось после 
    android:isScrollContainer="true"//добавления этих двоих с false
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">
  //поля ввода
  </ScrollView>
  <Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="99dp" />
  <ConstrainLayout
    //это нижняя кнопка
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3"
    ...>
  </ConstrainLayout>
</ConstrainLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать, чтобы вью не прыгали при скрытии клавиатуры и оставались на своих местах, путём вложения всей разметки в CoordinatorLayout с `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. В таком случае этот отступ можно нивелировать, сохранив расположение текстовых полей по верхнему краю, а кнопки снизу. ScrollView c атрибутом `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.